# aspx(ASP.NET4.0)のページから、htmlのページへ遷移したい。

Tags: javascript, asp.net

以下ASP.NET（VB.NET）で作成したあるWebページですが、イメージボタンが押下されたらセッション変数の値によってはまったく別のサイトのhtmlを開きたいです。（セッション変数が2でない時）
window.openを起動するJSをどのようにして動かせばよろしいでしょうか？
以下で画面が開きません

```
Protected Sub ImageButton2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs)
        If Session("UserLevel") <> "2" Then
            Dim startupScript As String = "<script language='JavaScript'> window.open('http://XXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXX/logon.html')</ Script > "
            Page.RegisterStartupScript("startup", startupScript)
        Else
            Server.Transfer("Menu2.aspx")
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: window.openを起動するJSをどのようにして動かせばよろしいでしょうか？ 以下で画面が開きません ⇒ 開かないのはポップアップブロックに引っかかているからでしょう。リダイレクトに変えるとか、根本的にやり方を考え直すべきかと思います。あと本題とは関係ない話ですが、Server.Transfer の使用はそれが絶対必要ということでない限り、避けることをお勧めします。

Answer (score 1):

`UserLevel`がページを表示してからクリックされるまでの間に変化しない前提ですが、

クリックされてからジャンプ先を判定するのではなく、`Page_Load`時にリンク先を設定してしまえばいいのでは？

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hyperLink1" NavigateUrl="Menu2.aspx" runat="server">
    <img src="something.png" />
</asp:HyperLink>

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Session("UserLevel") <> "2" Then
        hyperLink1.NavigateUrl = "http://XXXXXXXXXX/XXXXXXX/logon.html"
        hyperLink1.Target = "_blank"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: ご見解をありがとうございます。ImageButtonからHyperLinkへ早速変更させて頂きました。
いざ、という感じでデバッグを実行したら．．．

当該WebページがResponse.Redirectで遷移されてきていることが要因かPage_Loadイベントに入ってきていない？？？
ように見えます。If文でSession変数の内容を2か確認する部分に、ブレークポイントを仕掛けましたが、
停まらない．．．．
案の定　実行画面は当該ハイパリンクを押下すると、やはり初期設定のNavigastorUrlへ導かれます。

質問がズレてしまいますが、Page_Loadイベントが動作しないことなど　あるのでしょうか？？
（ServerTransferで入ってくれば良いのかな？？）


何から何まですみません

Comment: 当該ページをキャッシュ許可しているためにサーバーへ問い合わせすることなく表示完了してしまっています。本質的には各ページのキャッシュ可否を正しく設定することですが、簡易的には`Server.Transfer`を使いサーバー内でリダイレクトしてしまうことでしょうね。

Comment: 遷移元をServer.Transferにしたのですが、相変わらず
ImageButtonをHyperLinkに替えた問題のページが　Page_Loadイベントが動くて困っていて．．．．
デバッグモードだからでしょうか？　当該ページだけキャッシュ許可しない方法で解決できるのでしょうか、
その方法も分からない自分ですが